# how to customize kwrite to execute programs

Tags: linux, editor

kwrite is a file editor present in linux (PClinuxOS 2012)
can i customize kwrite to directly execute C programs directly from kwrite without leaving the kwrite editor , and to write the error to specified log file say error.log,
if yes where will i get reference material.

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try Kate instead. KWrite is just a simplified version of Kate nowadays.

It has the features you need.